# css positioning of submenus in bulk

Tags: css, css-float

The submenu's don't seem to align themselves at correct positions.

My html is:

```
<nav class="nav">
        <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li class="parent"><a href="#">PROFILE</a>
            <ul class="children submenu0">
                <li><a href="#">SIZE</a>

                 </li>
                 <li class="parent"><a href="#">NATURE</a>
                 <ul class="children submenu1">
                        <li><a href="#">SMALL</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">MEDIUM</a></li>
                    </ul>
                 </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>                 
  </nav>
```

And my css is as follows:

```
.nav{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    background-color: #000000;
    height: auto;
}

.nav .menu {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
}
.nav .menu li {
    float: left;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;   
}

.nav .menu .parent .children{
    float: none;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: -50px;
    width:auto;

}

.nav .menu .parent .children li{
    float:none; 
}
.nav .menu .parent .children li a {
    display: block;
    color:#C0F;
    background-color:#0FF;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.nav .menu li a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
.nav .menu .parent .children .parent .children {
    width:auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    float: none;
    position: absolute;

}
.nav .menu .parent .children .parent .children li a{
    display:block;
    color:#9C0;
    background-color:#F03;
    white-space:nowrap; 
}
```

When I add submenu1 to say size the alignment is all wrong even for nature its overlapping it instead of fitting perfectly next to it.

How do I get it to fit on its own.

Also my css is damn complicated so far is there any way I can simplify it so all the parent elemnts behave in a way and all children elements behave in a particular way irrespective of depth?

Comment: well, if you set the margin for your `.nav` class, you don't need to set the same again for `.nav .menu`, also you could use `margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px` for example to shorten your css... as to your question, pls provide more details on as to what you're trying to achieve exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three points to greater improve your submenu system

### Point 1: Use position relative, position absolute combo

Currently you are trying to use margins and padding to offset your menus but that will get messy fast because you can't guarantee widths unless you explicitly set them (ugly).  You should instead use the `position` attribute coupled with `top`, `right`, `bottom` and `left`.  This strategy involves setting the parent as `position:relative`.  The default `position` attribute is 'static'.  When you set it to `relative`, the element remains in document "document flow" and continues to take up space.

The key advantage is that when you then set a child element as `position:absolute`, that element is positioned relative to the parent.  e.g. with a parent having `position:relative` (or any attribute other than `static`, the default), and having a child with `position:absolute`, you can set the child to have `top:100%` and `left:0`.  This will set the top left corner of that element just below the bottom left corner of the parent.  `position:absolute` takes the element out of the document flow so it doesn't take up any space either.

#### Example ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bBR9J/show)|[Source](http://jsfiddle.net/bBR9J)):

HTML

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">parent</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">parent</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">parent width child</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">child</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">child</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">child</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">parent</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
/* reset padding and margin where necessary etc. */
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* just some quick demo styles for color whatnot */
nav {
    background: black;
    color: white;
}

nav ul ul {
    background: #555;
}

nav ul ul ul {
    background: #999;
}

nav a  {
    color: white;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

nav a:hover  {
    background: #f80;
}

/* important functional styles */
nav > ul:after {
    /* clear the float */
    content:'';
    clear:both;
    display: block;
}

nav li  {
    /* for the topmost level we want them to float.  will be overridden */
    float:left;
}

nav li a {
    /* always apply padding and display block to the a.  better user experience. */
    display:block;
    padding: 10px;
}

nav li ul li {
    /* overridden floating here */
    float: none;
}

/* here is where all the positioning takes place */
nav li {
    position:relative;
}

nav li ul {
    position:absolute;
    left: 0; /* for top most level lets align to the left */
    top: 100%; /* and have it at the bottom of the parent */
}
```

### Point 2: Override Styles

You need to use overrides.  That's how you can get around the whole messy CSS.  If you look think about what you are trying to do, you have the root submenus operating differently than the sub-submenus.  submenus have their top left corner aligned to the bottom left corner of the parent.  sub-submenus will have their top left corner aligned to the top right corner of their parent.  This will be easy with `position` attributes.

#### Example ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bBR9J/1/show)|[Source](http://jsfiddle.net/bBR9J/1)):

HTML

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">parent</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">parent</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">parent width child</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">child</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">child</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">child with children</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">grand child</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">grand child</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">parent</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
...

nav li ul li ul {
    left: 100%; /* for grandchild level lets align to the right of the list item */
    top: 0; /* and have it at the top of the parent li */
}
```

### Point 3: Immediate child selector

Although this is a little moot at this point, I think it's worth mentioning.  If you can't easily use overrides and you don't want a style to be inherited by an element's children, use the `>` selector modifier.  That way it only applies to the appropriate parent element.

```
nav > ul > li {
    /* special style here meant only for li's that are
       immediate child ul's that are immediate children
       of a nav element. */
}
```

Lastly, the complete [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bBR9J/2/show) and [source](http://jsfiddle.net/bBR9J/2/).

### Edit:

And yes, [it can go on indefinitely](http://jsfiddle.net/bBR9J/3/show).

Comment: WOW AMAZING!!!! it works exactly as i wanted...thanku so so much u r a life saver

Comment: @user3117694 You're welcome. Glad I could be of help. :)

Comment: hey joseph just tried to add the toogle part which was present in my previous code but its not working properly ...plz help tht too

Comment: @user3117694 this should probably be a separate question.  You'll need to post your current markup as well.

Comment: @user3117694 In your new answer you should post your most current code relevant to the issue (props if you use a http://jsfiddle.net demo), what you have tried, what exactly is going wrong (e.g. it disappears after first click or it pops up 5 px off etc.).  When that's done, throw a link in here and I'll have a look. I'll try my best to help but I can't promise anything unfortunately. I can only jump on here during lulls at work or my off time. :P

Comment: sure http://jsfiddle.net/LgE8u/  initially when i resize the browser the nav having home profile etc should disappear and MENU would pop up. on clicking it CLOSE MENU would come with the nav below ...its not working that way now

Comment: heres the new post link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575480/toggle-not-working-for-resize

Comment: hey joseph plz can u help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22790838/taxonomy-description-as-link

Answer (score 0):

Can you look at this: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/siva_hari/L7bPH/).

I updated the CSS, important line of css update was:

```
.nav .menu .parent .children .parent .children {
    width:auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: problem is this http://jsfiddle.net/L7bPH/1/..when i cchange the parent then children don't aling properly with same css