# toggle not working for resize

Tags: css, css-float

when i resize the browser the nav having home profile etc should disappear and MENU would pop up. on clicking it CLOSE MENU would come with the nav below but the background of close menu expanda height wise instead of being as it is..also after the toggle the menu goes behind the content and hover doesnt work

my html is as follows

```
<nav class="nav">
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" />
      <label for="toggle" class="toggle" data-open="MENU" data-close="Close Menu" onclick></label>
        <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li class="parent"><a href="#">PROFILE</a>
            <ul class="children submenu0">
                <li><a href="#">SIZE</a>

                 </li>
                 <li class="parent"><a href="#">NATURE</a>
                 <ul class="children submenu1">
                        <li><a href="#">SMALL</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">MEDIUM</a></li>
                    </ul>
                 </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>                 
  </nav>
```

...i have solved on my own ...thank to all who responded

Comment: I'm sorry.  I got caught up at work and didn't have time in edgewise this weekend.  Glad to see you resolved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing all `.ul` in your CSS with `ul` will solve your problem.

Comment: thanx...corrected that but the background of close menu expands instead of sticking to it original height with nav displayed separately below

Comment: @user3117694 It's not the background of close menu, but actually the background of `<nav>`, which is the parent of `<ul>`. You can change the background color of the close menu to have a look.

Comment: how do I stop tht from happening

Comment: ok i go tht corrected but the sub-submenu i.e grandchild don't appear also when content is present the menu goes behind the content plzhelp

Comment: @user3117694 Hmm...You'd better first consider how to arrange your sub-submenu (where and when to display), and reorganize your CSS code. And why not have a look how [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav) implements the feature? BTW, I don't think a complex navigation is suitable for mobile.