# taxonomy description as link

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i have a custom taxonomy created

```
// store
    $book_label = array(
        'name' => _x( 'stores', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'store', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search in store' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All store' ),
        'most_used_items' => null,
        'parent_item' => null,
        'parent_item_colon' => null,
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit store' ), 
        'update_item' => __( 'Update store' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add new store' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New store' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'stores' ),
    );
    register_taxonomy('stores', 'books',array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => $book_label,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'stores' )
    ));

    //
```

the store now allows me to enter nameand description in the description i am entering a url so that when adding posts based on the store name selected the url is auto selected too.

```
<?php
            $link = term_description( '', get_query_var( 'stores' ) );
            if($link != '') : ?>            

                <div class="click"><a href=<?php header('Location' .$link); ?>> BUY </a></div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
```

but on the front end the url is neither displayed nor redirected too....plz guide on where i am going wrong

Comment: There needs to be more information added.  For instance, I have no idea what the `term_description` and `header`.  Without that knowledge it's very hard to debug this code.

Comment: term_description function i used based on the http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/term_description

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell with only being able to see the pre-processed server side code, but if I were to guess, I'd say it's probably due to the fact that you don't have `"`s around your URL.  Thus the resulting anchor tag you're getting would be something like this:

```
<a href=http://example.com> BUY </a>
```

That will be invalid.  What you need is something like this:

```
<a href="<?php header('Location' .$link); ?>"> BUY </a>
```

Which will result in the following (assuming header `echo`s out a string):

```
<a href="http://example.com"> BUY </a>
```

It would be helpful for you to post the header function in your question as well.

Comment: header function was along the lines http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php